# Loading multiple templates based on route -- angular 2,4,5

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-routing

I have a scenario, in which I need to change component template based on URL but the logic is going to be same so I don't need separate component.

For instance, I have 2 URLs `localhost:3000/testin/why-me` and `localhost:3000/dev/why-me`

In both cases, I have same logic/component but I need to change UI with some minor look and feel differences. I have a component `why-me` with the following config.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'why-me',
  styleUrls: [ './why-me.component.scss' ],
  templateUrl: './why-me.component.html'
})
export class WhyMeComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor() {}

  public ngOnInit() {
    console.log('hello from `WhyMe` component')
  }
}
```

and my routes look like this

```
export const ROUTES: Routes = [
  { path: ':type/why-me', component: testin.WhyMeComponent },
  { path: '**',    component: NoContentComponent },
];
```

Now I have route type ie. `testin` or `dev` in route params, but how I can I give template conditionally? I searched a bit but wasn't able to find a better solution on Google.

Comment: The title says "load multiple templates" but you seem to have the reverse scenario: loading the same template (actually, component, which is critically different) on multiple routes?

Comment: what is way more not clear: you say you want the same component on both routes but you want to `give template conditionally` which means the component is far not the same. Because the component with totally different template (event if `.ts` is the same) is a totally different component. And it seems easy to solve in a normal way: just read the route parameter and use `*ngIf` / `[ngClass]` whatsoever in the template

Comment: That will increase size of HTML drastically. I am coming from a Angular 1.x background, and in Angular 1, we can set `controller` and `templateUrl` conditionally while defining routes.

Comment: Component is single entity in A2. You can either make parts of the template conditional, or inherit component class and make them 2 components.